# AngularJS - Recursive function disables $scope.on('destroy')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got a recursive function which calls another asynchronous function, and upon resolving the promise, calls itself again after a few seconds:

```
$scope.gamePolling = function () {
  if ($scope.getGames) {
    $scope.getGameData().then(function () {
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.gamePolling();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
};
```

When changing the route / state (using ui-router), I thought the $scope should be destroyed so I could turn off the recursive function using:

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function () {
  $scope.getGames = false;
});
```

However, on the next page the gamePolling function keeps calling itself because the breakpoint inside the destroy never gets hit.

So my question is **why isn't the $destroy event being triggered?**
p.s. this also happens when removing the $timeout, so the problem must be with the recursion.

I've gotten around this problem, by turning off gamePolling() in the $stateChangeStart:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
  $scope.getGames = false;
});
```

So the polling stops **but** the $destroy event still doesn't seem to be triggered.

As a little test, in state/controller A I assigned the current $scope to a $rootScope variable so I could check if it was destroyed in the state/controller B: `$rootScope.testScope = $scope;`

When checking `$rootScope.testScope.$$destroyed` in controller B, it returned **true**. So it looks like the $scope of the controller A was successfully destroyed. However, in $rootScope.testScope I can still access the variables that were assigned to $scope.

Comment: A cup of coffee may be.. try changing `'destroy'` to `'$destroy'`

Comment: That was it! Alex beat you to it by a few minutes, thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "$destroy" event, not "destroy"

It is funny because you mention the event with the right name and in the code you are missing the $ sign prefix.

Hope it helps!

UPDATE: If you allow me I suggest you use an interval instead of a timeout+recursive function. You can then "kill" the interval in the $destroy event handler.

Comment: ...I've been looking at this for 2 days and completely missed this, thinking the problem was much more complex. Thank you so much!

Regarding the interval: I'm actually changing this from an interval, because the inner method does a backend request and on slow connections this was leading to many requests being sent even though there were still some pending.